# Stream Analytics conditional check

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I'm preparing proof of concept for azure iot . I send data from device a to azure iot hub and from iot hub sending data to database via stream analytics.

Question is : I want to check if I have this record in database if not I want to add record. And I want to create "start time" when some certain event occurred  and "finish time" event is finished so I need to update row. Is it possible with stream analytics and is stream analytics correct place to do this kind of checks ?

Comment: how many messages are we talking about per second. And of what size and format? Also, what database will it go to?

Comment: max 2-3 messages per second.im posting as json format. it will go to azure sql database. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure to only add one record in the database, you can follow the instructions on our team blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2017/01/13/how-to-achieve-exactly-once-delivery-for-sql-output/

Thanks,
JS - Azure Stream Analytics

Comment: Thank you for answer. I applied solution like i explained in comment at Kartal's answer.

Answer (score 0):

actually Im not Sure but hope its helps.

U cannot update your database.

Azure Stream Analytics is works for stream your data.

I think you have a 2 option for this case

One way you can keep your data on temptable on stream analytics you can check your conditions and insert database but its not work with older datas

second way u can use trigger on your database.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerDataFromStream
ON DataFromStream
AFTER INSERT
AS
```

Like this.

Comment: Thank you Kartal.  I think I'm close to what I wanted to do. As you mentioned stream analytics  is not the correct place to apply this kind of operations. I created Service bus and routed iot hub messages to this service bus. Then I created function app and I configured this function to be triggered by service bus queue. So far I can see my data in function app. I think I can apply other operation that I wanted from function app. Thanks again for both of you

Comment: Thank you Peter. It seems service bus also accepting message outside without iot Hub (I didn't try this ) if so this can be option maybe but you will not be using benefits of iot hubs.